# vsprintf() says I dont have enought arguments but I do

Tags: php, printf

On `$content` I have 22 times `{text}`. I want that each one of them will be changed to something in the array, so I build the function `replace()`, but I'm reciving this error:

> ( ! ) Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments in
>   C:\wamp\www\sitepro\tample.php on line 12

I used `count()` on the array and I recived 22. When I'm adding `"",` to the array in the beginning, the error disappears, and the first `{text}` is empty, but when I'm adding `,""` to the end of the array I'm still revicing the error.

It's not the first use of this function, it works fine except this time.

```
function replace($text, $find, $replace){
    global $content;
    $content = vsprintf(str_replace($find, "%s", $content), $replace); // Line 12
    return $content;
}

$content = replace($content, "{text}", ["גם אתר זה נבנה באמצעות SelfSite", "על מנת לערוך את תוכן האתר, לחץ על טקסט האתר. לעריכת תמונה, יש ללחוץ עליה לחיצה כפולה. לאפשרויות ומידע נוסף לחץ על גלגל השיניים בצד שמאל למעלה באתר.&nbsp;<b>בהצלחה!</b>", "תיק עבודות","אני עם החברה", "עבודה שלי שפורסמה בישראל היום", "מוזה", "בין העבודות האהובות עליי!", "שלום אסייג", "דומה, לא?", "צוות", "ישראל ישראלי", "מנכ\"ל החברהת, מעצב אתרים, פוסטרים, כרטיסי ביקור ועוד.", "אלמוני אלמוני", "ראש צוות מפתחים. מומחה בשפות התכנות html, css, js, php ו-sql", "אני", "מייסד החברה. מאייר לחברות גדולות, בינהם ישראל היום.","עדכונים", "<b>12.05.14&nbsp;</b>נפתח האתר החדש! אנו רוצים להודות לחברת SelfSite על הכלי הנוח והתמיכה המיידית בכל נושא שיש. &nbsp;יש שגיאה באתר? צרו איתנו קשר!<br><br><strong>30.04.14&nbsp;</strong>זכייה בפרס ישראל לאומנות מישרארט, קהילת המעצבים הישראלית, <a data-cke-saved-href=\"http://www.isrart.co.il\" href=\"http://www.isrart.co.il\">www.isrart.co.il</a>!<br><br><strong>15.03.14&nbsp;</strong>ישראל ישראלי מצטרף כמנכ\"ל החברה! נאחל לו בהצלחה!<br>","מי אנחנו?", "חברת&nbsp;<strong>א</strong>נחנו-<b>א</b>ומנות&nbsp;מתמקדת בכל סוגי האומנות. החל מעיצוב אתרים ועד להלחנת שירים. כל אחד מחברי הצוות מומחה בתחומו. כל חברי הצוות יצירתיים ומספקים את העבודה הטובה ביותר שיכל להיות. צרו איתנו קשר דרך ה<a data-cke-saved-href=\"http://facebook.com/me\" href=\"http://facebook.com/me\">פייסבוק</a>, ה<a data-cke-saved-href=\"http://twitter.com/me\" href=\"http://twitter.com/me\">טוויטר</a> או באמצעות ה<a data-cke-saved-href=\"mailto:we@design.co.il\" href=\"mailto:we@design.co.il\">אימייל</a>.","עובד השבוע", "<img data-cke-saved-src=\"http://localhost/sitepro/1/img/demo/team1.png\" src=\"http://localhost/sitepro/1/img/demo/team1.png\" alt=\"Post Title\" style=\"width: 100%;\">"]);
```

I cannot upload `$content` because it's a very long code, but I'm shure that there are only 22 `{text}`.
What is the problem?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
Please try to explain *what you want to achieve* and not state *this code does not solve my problem*

Comment: @dognose `On $content I have 22 times {text}. I want that each one of them will be changed to something in the array, so I build the function replace(), but I'm reciving this error:...` Basically there is an html code of a template, and anywhere should be text I've added `{text}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can ommit that global stuff. You are passing content as argument anyway (named `text` in the scope of the replace-method). Use:

```
function replace($text, $find, $replace){
    $content = vsprintf(str_replace($find, "%s", $text), $replace); 
    return $content;
}
```

works as expected. If just one `{text}` is found, only one gets replaced.

If more than `array count` occurences of `{text}` are found inside `$content`, you receive the error you are mentioning.

So, you are trying to replace `n` matches of `{text}` with an array containing `n-1` elements. That's why adding an additional blank element (`""`) solves the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMedico saw that :)